# Visual representation of mind and kamma

Tags: mind, fetters

Is there a visual representation of how mind looks like with kamma, feelings, emotions, perceptions, attachments etc. Like for example, I tend to visualize lust as a tether that binds us to this human place and locks our mind from our understanding and penetrating the true nature of things as it prevents development of concentration, and thus wisdom. Likewise I am looking for somewhat intuitive understanding of mind and kamma.

Any one?

Answer (score 1):

The famous monkey mind simile of [SN 12.61](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.061.than.html#monkey) is one.

> "It would be better for the uninstructed run-of-the-mill person to
> hold to the body composed of the four great elements, rather than the
> mind, as the self. Why is that? Because this body composed of the four
> great elements is seen standing for a year, two years, three, four,
> five, ten, twenty, thirty, forty, fifty, a hundred years or more. But
> what's called 'mind,' 'intellect,' or 'consciousness' by day and by
> night arises as one thing and ceases as another. Just as a monkey,
> swinging through a forest wilderness, grabs a branch. Letting go of
> it, it grabs another branch. Letting go of that, it grabs another one.
> Letting go of that, it grabs another one. In the same way, what's
> called 'mind,' 'intellect,' or 'consciousness' by day and by night
> arises as one thing and ceases as another.
> [SN 12.61](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.061.than.html#monkey)

The simile of the six animals from [SN 35.237](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.247/en/bodhi) may be fitting your request well. Please see below.

The suttas also contain many such similes, for e.g. the similes of [SN 12.63](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.63/en/bodhi).

Please take a look at AccessToInsight's [Index of Similes](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/index-similes.html).

> “Bhikkhus, suppose a man with limbs wounded and festering would enter
> a wood of thorny reeds, and the Kusa thorns would prick his feet and
> the reed blades would slash his limbs. Thus that man would thereby
> experience even more pain and displeasure. So too, bhikkhus, some
> bhikkhu here, gone to the village or the forest, meets someone who
> reproaches him thus: ‘This venerable one, acting in such a way,
> behaving in such a way, is a foul village thorn.’ Having understood
> him thus as a ‘thorn,’ one should understand restraint and
> nonrestraint.
>
> “And how, bhikkhus is there nonrestraint? Here, having seen a form
> with the eye, a bhikkhu is intent upon a pleasing form and repelled by
> a displeasing form. He dwells without having set up mindfulness of the
> body, with a limited mind, and he does not understand as it really is
> that liberation of mind, liberation by wisdom, wherein those evil
> unwholesome states cease without remainder. Having heard a sound with
> the ear … Having cognized a mental phenomenon with the mind, he is
> intent upon a pleasing mental phenomenon and repelled by a displeasing
> mental phenomenon. He dwells without having set up mindfulness of the
> body, with a limited mind, and he does not understand as it really is
> that liberation of mind, liberation by wisdom, wherein those evil
> unwholesome states cease without remainder.
>
> “Suppose, bhikkhus, a man would catch six animals—with different
> domains and different feeding grounds—and tie them by a strong rope.
> He would catch a snake, a crocodile, a bird, a dog, a jackal, and a
> monkey, and tie each by a strong rope. Having done so, he would tie
> the ropes together with a knot in the middle and release them. Then
> those six animals with different domains and different feeding grounds
> would each pull in the direction of its own feeding ground and domain.
> The snake would pull one way, thinking, ‘Let me enter an anthill.’ The
> crocodile would pull another way, thinking, ‘Let me enter the water.’
> The bird would pull another way, thinking, ‘Let me fly up into the
> sky.’ The dog would pull another way, thinking, ‘Let me enter a
> village.’ The jackal would pull another way, thinking, ‘Let me enter a
> charnel ground.’ The monkey would pull another way, thinking, ‘Let me
> enter a forest.’
>
> “Now when these six animals become worn out and fatigued, they would
> be dominated by the one among them that was strongest; they would
> submit to it and come under its control. So too, bhikkhus, when a
> bhikkhu has not developed and cultivated mindfulness directed to the
> body, the eye pulls in the direction of agreeable forms and
> disagreeable forms are repulsive; the ear pulls in the direction of
> agreeable sounds and disagreeable sounds are repulsive; the nose pulls
> in the direction of agreeable odours and disagreeable odours are
> repulsive; the tongue pulls in the direction of agreeable tastes and
> disagreeable tastes are repulsive; the body pulls in the direction of
> agreeable tactile objects and disagreeable tactile objects are
> repulsive; the mind pulls in the direction of agreeable mental
> phenomena and disagreeable mental phenomena are repulsive.
>
> “It is in such a way that there is nonrestraint.
>
> “And how, bhikkhus, is there restraint? Here, having seen a form with
> the eye, a bhikkhu is not intent upon a pleasing form and not repelled
> by a displeasing form. He dwells having set up mindfulness of the
> body, with a measureless mind, and he understands as it really is that
> liberation of mind, liberation by wisdom, wherein those evil
> unwholesome states cease without remainder. Having heard a sound with
> the ear … Having cognized a mental phenomenon with the mind, he is not
> intent upon a pleasing mental phenomenon and not repelled by a
> displeasing mental phenomenon. He dwells having set up mindfulness of
> the body, with a measureless mind, and he understands as it really is
> that liberation of mind, liberation by wisdom, wherein those evil
> unwholesome states cease without remainder. It is in such a way that
> there is restraint.
>
> “Suppose, bhikkhus, a man would catch six animals—with different
> domains and different feeding grounds—and tie them by a strong rope.
> He would catch a snake, a crocodile, a bird, a dog, a jackal, and a
> monkey, and tie each by a strong rope. Having done so, he would bind
> them to a strong post or pillar. Then those six animals with different
> domains and different feeding grounds would each pull in the direction
> of its own feeding ground and domain. The snake would pull one way,
> thinking, ‘Let me enter an anthill’ … as above … The monkey would pull
> another way, thinking, ‘Let me enter a forest.’
>
> “Now when these six animals become worn out and fatigued, they would
> stand close to that post or pillar, they would sit down there, they
> would lie down there. So too, bhikkhus, when a bhikkhu has developed
> and cultivated mindfulness directed to the body, the eye does not pull
> in the direction of agreeable forms nor are disagreeable forms
> repulsive; the ear does not pull in the direction of agreeable sounds
> nor are disagreeable sounds repulsive; the nose does not pull in the
> direction of agreeable odours nor are disagreeable odours repulsive;
> the tongue does not pull in the direction of agreeable tastes nor are
> disagreeable tastes repulsive; the body does not pull in the direction
> of agreeable tactile objects nor are disagreeable tactile objects
> repulsive; the mind does not pull in the direction of agreeable mental
> phenomena nor are disagreeable mental phenomena repulsive.
>
> “It is in such a way that there is restraint.
>
> “‘A strong post or pillar’: this, bhikkhus, is a designation for
> mindfulness directed to the body. Therefore, bhikkhus, you should
> train yourselves thus: ‘We will develop and cultivate mindfulness
> directed to the body, make it our vehicle, make it our basis,
> stabilize it, exercise ourselves in it, and fully perfect it.’ Thus
> should you train yourselves.”
>
> [SN 35.237 - The Simile of the Six Animals](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.247/en/bodhi)